# OverlapAreaAll не находит коллайдер unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ситуация такая: есть метод, который перемещает все коробки на уровне в начальное положение.

```
private void OnPlayerinteract(Transform player)
{
    if (Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position) < TriggerDiastance)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
        {
            boxes[i].position = puzzleData.GetBoxPosIndex(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < levers.Length; i++)
        {
            levers[i].SwitchLaver(puzzleData.GetLeverStateIndex(i));
        }
    }
    RestartPuzzle?.Invoke();
}
```

Событие RestartPuzzle вызывает метод на нажимных плитах, чтобы они проверили, есть ли на них только что перемещенные коробки.
Вот этот метод:

```
private void CheckColliders()
{
    Collider2D[] collider2Ds = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(
        new Vector2((transform.position.x - transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y - transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)),
        new Vector2((transform.position.x + transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y + transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)));
    Debug.DrawLine(
        new Vector2((transform.position.x - transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y - transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)),
        new Vector2((transform.position.x + transform.localScale.x / 2 * 0.8f), (transform.position.y + transform.localScale.y / 2 * 0.8f)),
        Color.blue,
        100f);
    foreach (var item in collider2Ds)
    {
        if (item.GetComponent<Presser>())
        {
            Debug.Log(item.name);
            signalState = SignalState.On;
            foreach (Interactable i in Interactables)
            {
                i.OnTriggerDone();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Метод CheckColliders находит только коллайдер нажимной плиты, хотя коробка находится внутри области.
Есть какие-то мысли?

Update: коллайдер находится если воспроизвести метод 2 раза(то есть для игрока нажать кнопку 2 раза). Выходит что коробка находится если уже стоит внутри зоны, если же она телепортируется из другого места то OverlapAreaAll ее не видит. Надеюсь это улучшит понимание проблемы

Update 2: если я проверяю коллайдер после задержки 0,05 секунды, все работает отлично, но как я могу сделать это без задержки? Это не должно быть проблемой, но почему Unity не может найти коллайдер, если его перемещение было сделано до проверки?

Answer (score 1):

`Overlap` значит что объект должен не просто касаться, а полностью находиться внутри зоны.

Для начала нормально отрисуй эту зону.

```
private List<Vector3> _targets = new List<Vector3>();

private void Update ()
{
    Collider2D[] targets = Physics2D.OverlapAreaAll(
        (Vector2)(transform.position - transform.localScale * 0.5f),
        (Vector2)(transform.position + transform.localScale * 0.5f));
    _targets.Clear();
    _targets.AddRange(targets.Select(t => t.transform.position));
}

private void OnDrawGizmos ()
{
    Gizmos.color = new Color(0, 0.4f, 1);
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, transform.localScale);

    Gizmos.color = new Color(1, 0.4f, 0);
    float crossSize = 3;
    foreach (Vector3 target in _targets)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(target - Vector3.up * crossSize, target + Vector3.up * crossSize);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(target - Vector3.right * crossSize, target + Vector3.right * crossSize);
    }
}
```

---

Если условие на касание, то используется `Physics2D.BoxCastAll()`.

Comment: У меня коллайдер находится 100% внутри зоны, сейчас попробую BoxCastAll()

Comment: Работает как ReycastAll(), только не лучём, а проекцией куба.